# No such file or directory: 'arm-none-eabi-gcc' error trying to make micropython for STM32

Tags: macos, micropython

I am following the [documentation](https://github.com/micropython/micropython#the-stm32-version) for building micropython

```
cd mpy-cross
make
```

And then installed the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) as I am using a Mac with OSX. Then I proceeded to

```
cd ../ports/stm32
make submodules
make
```

and got the error

```
Use make V=1 or set BUILD_VERBOSE in your environment to increase build verbosity.
mkdir -p build-PYBV10/genhdr
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/pins.h
GEN stmconst build-PYBV10/modstm_qstr.h
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/pybcdc.inf
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/pybcdc_inf.h
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/pllfreqtable.h
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/mpversion.h
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/moduledefs.h
GEN build-PYBV10/genhdr/qstr.i.last
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../py/makeqstrdefs.py", line 188, in <module>
    preprocess()
  File "../../py/makeqstrdefs.py", line 62, in preprocess
    for output in p.imap(pp(flags), chunks):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 748, in next
    raise value
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "../../py/makeqstrdefs.py", line 46, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(args.pp + flags + files)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arm-none-eabi-gcc': 'arm-none-eabi-gcc'
make: *** [build-PYBV10/genhdr/qstr.i.last] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `build-PYBV10/genhdr/qstr.i.last'
```

I've looked at the docs for the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain, but it doesn't appear that I missed a step. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the installer did not put the binaries in my path. I fixed this with

```
export PATH="/Applications/ARM/bin:$PATH"
```

and then was able to run `make` without error.